# adding a slicer for specific values of variable

Tags: excel

I currently have a pivot table and pivot chart in which I am using a slicer to filter on certain values of `Name`.

As you can see there are 8 different values of `Name` however there are only four different elements withing this `A001`,`B002`,`C001` & `D001`. I would like to use the slicer to only show the values of `A001`,`B002`,`C001` & `D001`.

The way it should work is follows: If I select `A001` I want the values from `Name` of `A001`,`B002`,`A001_C001_B002`, `C001_A001` & `C001_D001_A001`. (Basically I want all combinations of A001 to show up).

Is there anyway to do this in excel?

Thanks.

[image: slicer pivot chart]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do what you are looking for. Both require you to define the groups once:

First option is to add another column to your original data with the overall group and then use that group in the slicer.

The alternative is to group the values in pivot. For a description how to do that please have a look [here](https://www.auditexcel.co.za/blog/grouping-items-in-pivot-table-slicers/).